# Vim editor indent problem when the first character of the line is a sharp # character

Tags: vim, indentation

This haven been bugging me since the first day using Vim for 3 years. Whenever I try to indent a line via <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> when the FIRST CHARACTER of the line starts with a "#", it doesn't work at all, regardless of the file types (.php, .txt, etc.). Because # is used for comment in PHP and I also use it for decoration for text files something like:

```
# This is a comment

### 1. Instruction one

# ------------ this is an sample --------------
```

I use Vim 7.2 in Ubuntu with the following `.vimrc` settings

```
syntax on
set t_Co=256
set incsearch
set hlsearch
set number
set nowrap
set nowrapscan
set ignorecase
set et
set sw=4
set smarttab
set smartindent
set autoindent
set textwidth=0
set noequalalways
set formatoptions=1
set lbr
set vb      
set foldmethod=marker
```

Answer (score 4):

Insert the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
set nosmartindent
```

It is `smartindent` that causes lines beginning with `#` to not be indented as you want. You can read more about it by typing `:help smartindent`. If you use an indenting file for python scripts (or any other syntax), include the following too.

```
filetype indent on
```

Comment: This does not solve it for me. I have `nosmartindent` and `filetype indent on` and still vim does not let me indent lines starting with `#`. It also moves the cursor to the first column whenver i type `#` as first character in a line. Any clues?

Comment: @MichaelHärtl I had your exact same problem, by default .Rmd has this annoying behavior on by default, the proper incantation that toggles this behavior is: `:set nocindent` to turn it off and `:set cindent` to turn it back on, as defined here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
inoremap # X^H#
```

I think this behaviour is not totally wrong for C/C++, therefore I just change it in python/php.

```
autocmd FileType python,php inoremap # X^H#
```

`:help smartindent` says:

When typing `#` as the first character in a new line, the indent for
that line is removed, the `#` is put in the first column.  The indent
is restored for the next line.

If you don't want this, use this mapping: `:inoremap # X^H#`, where `^H` is entered with `CTRL-V CTRL-H`.
When using the `>>` command, lines starting with `#` are not shifted right.

Answer (score 0):

After asking ChatGPT, I finally found the solution.

By default, vim set foldignore as `#`, you can verify it by running this command in vim:

```
set foldignore?
```

You will see the output `foldignore=#`.

**Solution**: add this to your vim config:

```
set foldignore=
```